# Behavior in Delphi Documentation Viewer

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2, help-system

Delphi XE2 Update 4 Hotfix 1 and Help Update 6 for XE2.

If I am in the IDE, highlight an object name such as TLabel, then hit F1, I am transported to the description of Vcl.StdCtrls.TLabel in Delphi's help application. The page gives me information for both the Delphi and C++, but I can click on Display Preferences in the top right and 'un-tick' C++ so only the Delphi information is displayed. But now, if I click on TEdit (either by clicking within the help page under See Also or by selecting and F1-ing in the IDE), the Display Preferences automagically reverts to both Delphi and C++ when the TEdit Help is displayed.

If, on the other hand, I go directly to embarcadero online help, for example: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TLabel to get the same information (using Chrome), the browser (?) remembers my Display Preferences and, once I have un-clicked C++, will only show me the Delphi information if I click on TEdit or further pages.

This drives me to distraction, as I am not the least interested in C++. Have I missed some option within XE2 to only select Delphi in Help's Display Preferences, or is this a 'feature'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything you can do with XE2's docs to fix this.

This was improved on in XE3's documentation, and improved even further in XE4's and since there have been four versions released since XE2 there won't be any further updates to it.

(You can't compare the online documentation with the local disk documentation; the first uses the functionality of the web browser, while the second uses the functionality in the MS documentation viewer, which happens to contain a web browser control but implements the functionality in the app itself instead.)

*Answer by Ken White*